# Page is empty and I can see only titles

Tags: pdftex, luatex, pdf

I dont know what happened I can see only the titles i.e "List of Tables" and "Contents" and the rest of the page is empty. Here is the list of packages I used in my code to write thesis. Comments will really be to appreciated.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\let\circledS\undefined % here - PS
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{scalerel}
%\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
%\textwidth=450pt\oddsidemargin=0pt
%\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=42mm,rmargin=25mm}
%\newgeometry{top=1in,bottom=1in,outer=1in,inner=2in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[pdftex, breaklinks=true, colorlinks=true,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={red}]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linktocpage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Did you compile several times?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but make sure that you don't load packages more than once.

Comment: and post a fully compilable MWE, please...

Comment: @ Bernard: your comment solved my problem.

Comment: @leandriis: I am still getting errors related to that but I keep pressing the "Enter" key to produce the pdf anyway. Please suggest me what are the overlapping packages I had used?

Comment: We cannot test your document as it is incomplete.

Comment: @Higgs: Please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error. I was specifically referring to the `graphicx` package that you load twice with different options.

Comment: @Higgs: Also unrelated, but you might want to keep in mind that the `subfigure` package is deprecated. You might want to replace it with either `subfig` or `subcaption`. Apart from that, the `mathdesign` and the `amsmath`/`amsfonts` packages also shouldn't be used together (see corresponding warning).

Comment: It should not be necessary, and it may in fact be problematic, to specify the option `pdftex` when loading `hyperref`.